# upload image and access laravel 5

Tags: php, upload, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5 and i want to upload the user's profile picture.
My upload is working but I do not know how to get the image to the folder.
Someone could help me?

**Controller**

```
public function updateProfile() {
    $profileData = Input::except('_token');
    $validation = Validator::make($profileData, User::$profileData);
    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $file = array_get($profileData,'imagem');
        $destinationPath = 'imagens/perfil';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        User::where('id', Input::get('id'))->update($profileData);
        return view('backend/perfil.index')->with('message', 'Updated Succesfully');
    } else {
        return view('backend/perfil.index')->with('message', $validation->messages());
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('backend/perfil', 'BackendControlador@updateProfile');
```

**Index**

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " align="center"> 
        <img alt="User Pic" src="{{ Auth::user()->imagem}}" class="img-circle img-responsive"> 
    </div>


{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'url' => 'backend/perfil', 'name' => 'updateProfile', 'role' => 'form', 'files'=> true))!!}

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">


        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                {!! Form::label('imagem', 'Imagem', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::file('imagem', ['class' => 'input-file']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 30px;">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                {!! Form::submit('Alterar perfil', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        </div> 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: `how to get the image to the folder` It means you don't know how to retrieve or you having issue in storing image itself ?

Comment: what do you mean? my problem is you can not get the image in the file view

Comment: You mean listing all the images like `Preview` or getting single image in a page  ?

Comment: Single image in a page. In this case in my profile

Comment: I managed to create but is not the best method and want to change.

Comment: You having the image's path in database ? If so, why not just doing this `<img src="$yourImagePathFromDB">` ?

Comment: I don't to insert the picture into DB not to get a very large database. It was for that I created a folder in the public and only then do I have the pictures.

Comment: Ok, You saving the image path in db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the op's comment i guess that op is not saving the image's path in Database.

**How can you do that**

**Step 1 :**

Whenever save the image, save the path of the image in database with some identity.

**Step 2 :**

Retrieve the image's path from Database and have it inside the `img src` tag

i.e.,

`$yourImagePath = 'xyz.jpg'; # Retrieved from DB`

then

`<img src='<?php echo $yourImagePath?>'>`

Comment: I haven't field in the db called image.
It is better to create a field in the database only for the way?

Comment: Yeah, no other go, because we need to identify the image in some unique way. We can' simply show the images from the asset folder :) ;)

Comment: Sure, also if you stuck up in any syntax/logic you shall ask ;)

Comment: My path is C:\xampp\tmp\phpE683.tmp as is possible?

Comment: Ahm, i guess you're seeing the temporary path, Are you moving the images under asset folder of your laravel application ?

Comment: The only thing I do is to change the image, update the public folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95102/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-jose-cerejo).

Answer (score -1):

instead of this line

```
$destinationPath = 'imagens/perfil';
```

just try the following code

```
$destinationPath = publicpath().'imagens/perfil';
```